# Minimal polynomial for symmetric form and linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

I'm hoping to get help with the following problem.

> Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbf{R}$ with $\mathrm{dim}~V = n < \infty$. Let $(\cdot, \cdot): V \times V \to \mathbf{R}$ be a positive definite symmetric form, and suppose the linear map $f: V \to V$ satisfies $(f(u), v) = (u, f(v))$ for each $u, v \in V$. Show that the minimal polynomial of $f$ 
>   splits.

I am stuck on this. I know that the minimal polynomial of $f$ splits with distinct roots if and only if the matrix of $f$ is diagonalizable. So I tried to use this fact. I have shown that $(\cdot, \cdot)$ can be represented as the identity matrix in a basis $e_1, \dots, e_n$ with $(e_i, e_j) = \delta_{ij}$, but now I'm stuck.

**Edit:** I've updated the comment above to clarify the equivalence holds iff the roots are distinct. This is an additional assumption not given in the problem, so I may not be going down the right track. Any hints would be helpful!

Comment: When you say a polynomial splits, I assume you mean that it factors completely into linear factors. In which case the minimal polynomial of a linear transformation can split without the linear transformation being diagonalizable. For example $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, which has minimal polynomial $x^2$.

Comment: @jgon you are right. the equivalence holds only when we assume that that it splits with distinct roots. I'll update the post accordingly. my bad!

Comment: @jgon:  I believe that the assumption that $f$ is symmetric precludes this possibility.

Comment: @Robert Lewis: $f$ is not symmetric, only $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is. I've improved the title of the question to make this clearer. My apologies

Comment: Here's the thing:  your symmetric form $(\cdot, \cdot)$, being positive definite, defines an inner product on $V$ which is essentially no different than the ordinary $\cdot$ product of vectors in $\Bbb R^n$, as your construction of a basis such that $(e_i, e_j) = \delta_{ij}$ shows.  With this inner product, $f$ *is* a symmetric operator, that's what $(f(u), v) = (u, f(v))$ means.  So all the arguments about symmetric operators with respect to the usual inner product on $\Bbb R^n$ should apply here as well.

Comment: @RobertLewis: Right. I was thinking about this, because in this basis, the symmetric form becomes the usual Euclidean dot product.

Comment: @NoetherThingToDo:  right, so all the arguments from Euclidean space apply.

Comment: @RobertLewis. Thanks. Can you give me any hint as to how to proceed here?

Comment: @NoetherThingToDo:  Maybe.  Let me think a little more on it and get back to you.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First answer, without tensor products.

Suppose the minimal polynomial of the linear transformation did not split. For my comfort, I'm going to use $T$ for the linear transformation and $m_T(t)$ for it's minimal polynomial. Then $m_T(t)$ factors into some number of linear factors and at least one irreducible quadratic factor. Let $t^2 + 2at+b$ be this quadratic factor. Since the quadratic factor is irreducible, we have that its discriminant, $d=4a^2-4b$, is negative. Let $\delta = -d/4$, so that $\delta = b-a^2$ is positive. Now we can complete the square to rewrite $m_T(t)$ as $(t+a)^2 +(b-a^2)=(t+a)^2+\delta$. Then we have that for any $u\ne 0\in V$,
$$ (((T+a)^2 + \delta) u,u) = ((T+a)^2 u,u) + \delta(u,u)$$
$$ = ((T+a)u,(T+a)u) + \delta(u,u)=\|(T+a)u\|^2+\delta\|u\|^2>0.$$

However, since $t^2+at+b$ is a factor of the minimal polynomial of $T$, $T^2+aT+b$ must not be invertible (otherwise we could find a smaller polynomial which is 0 when evaluated at $T$ by removing this factor), so there is some $u\ne 0 \in V$ for which $(T^2+aT+b)u=0$, but then $((T^2+aT+b)u,u)=0$, which is a contradiction of the above inequality. Hence the minimal polynomial of $T$ cannot contain any irreducible quadratic factors.

Second answer, with tensor products.

We can make this into a question about complex vector spaces and Hermitian operators. Let $\newcommand{\tens}{\otimes}\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb{C}}W=\CC\tens V$. Now we need to extend our original bilinear form, which I will call $B$, to a Hermitian form, $\phi$, defined on $W\times W$. This can be done by defining $\phi(\alpha \tens v, \beta \tens w)= \alpha\overline{\beta} B(v,w)$ and extending by linearity. Then if $A : V\to V$ was our old linear operator, we can extend $A$ to $W$ by tensoring with $1=\newcommand{\id}{\text{id}}\id_\CC$, to get $T=1\tens A : W\to W$. Now $T$ is Hermitian, since 
$$\phi(T(\alpha \tens v),\beta \tens w) 
= \phi(\alpha \tens Av,\beta \tens w)
= \alpha\overline{\beta} B(Av,w)
=\alpha\overline{\beta} B(v,Aw)
= \phi(\alpha \tens v,\beta \tens Aw)
=\phi(\alpha \tens v,T(\beta \tens w)).$$
Now let $\lambda\in\CC$ be an eigenvalue of $T$ with eigenvector $v$,
then $\lambda\phi(v,v)=\phi(\lambda v,v)=\phi(Tv,v)=\phi(v,Tv)=\phi(v,\lambda v)=\overline{\lambda}\phi(v,v)$. Hence $\lambda = \overline{\lambda}$, so all of $T$'s eigenvalues are real. Hence the minimal polynomial of $T$ has real roots, and hence is a real polynomial.

Then $m_T(A)$ makes sense, and we want to show that it's zero so that we can say that $m_A(t)\mid m_T(t)$, and therefore say that all of the roots of $m_A(t)$ are real (hence $m_A(t)$ splits). Suppose $m_T(A)\ne 0$, then $m_T(A) u\ne 0$ for some $u\in V$. However then $0=m_T(T)(1\tens u) = m_T(1\tens A) (1\tens u) = (1\tens m_T(A))(1\tens u) = 1\tens (m_T(A)u) \ne 0$, which is a contradiction. Therefore $m_T(A)=0$, so $m_A(t)$ has all of its roots in the reals. Hence $m_A(t)$ splits.

Comment: Can you explain why we know that if it does not split, then for sure it has a quadratic factor?

Comment: @NoetherThingToDo Irreducible real polynomials are either linear, or quadratics of the form $(t-z)(t-\overline{z})$ for some nonreal complex number $z$. Thus if the polynomial has an irreducible factor which isn't a linear factor, it must be an irreducible quadratic.

Comment: @NoetherThingToDo:  yes, it comes from the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, which allows us to to conclude that a degree $n$ polynomial has $n$ roots; if the coefficients are real, then complex roots must occur in conjugate pairs, giving rise to the real irreducible quadratic factors.

Comment: @NoetherThingToDo:  still thinking about it.

Comment: +1 to @jgon for providing two answers. Much appreciated!

Comment: @NoetherThingToDo Np, the second answer was mostly because I was inspired by your comment on complexifying things, and I realized that that was probably a valid path. Thinking about whether or not it's possible to do without the FTOA. I suspect not, but I'll think a bit more.

Comment: @jgon: Can you clarify this line: $\lambda \phi(v,v)=\phi(Tv,v)=\phi(v,Tv)=\phi(v, \lambda v)= \overline{λ}\phi(v,v)$? How do we know that $\lambda \phi(v, v) = \phi(Tv, v)$? Are you saying that $\lambda \phi(v, v) = \phi(\lambda v, v) = \phi(Tv, v)$, using first bilinearity and second, that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue? Also, how do we know that the extension $\phi$ is bilinear?

Comment: Sorry, yes to your first question, I'll edit that to be more clear. Also I presume you mean the extension $\phi$? $\phi$ is not bilinear, it's sesquilinear, i.e., it's conjugate linear in the second argument, and that's fairly simple to check just from the definition of $\phi$ using the fact that $B$ is already bilinear.

Comment: Ah I see. And yes, of course I meant $\phi$ :).

Comment: @jgon Can you explain what the motivation is for taking $ϕ(\alpha \otimes v,\beta \otimes w)=\alpha \overline{\beta}B(v,w)$? What goes wrong if you don't conjugate $\beta$?

Comment: Well that's how we get $\lambda = \overline{\lambda}$, also sesquilinear (Hermitian) forms are the right thing for complex vector spaces because we want $\phi(v,v)\in\mathbb{R}$, and if $\phi$ is Hermitian (i.e. if $\phi(u,v)=\overline{\phi(v,u)}$), $\phi(v,v)=\overline{\phi(v,v)}$, which implies $\phi(v,v)\in\mathbb{R}$.